# Chat notification like skype in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a desktop chat application in JavaFX. I want to show notification to the user when application is minimized like skype shows that.Is there any way of doing it? I had tried System tray of java but it was not working for Ubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you sharing us your application please

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [ControlFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) [Notifications](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#notifications) component. I think it's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Seems to not work anymore in 2016, just thought i should mention.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this question in 2020, here's a stab at showing native OS notifications working with JavaFX:

https://gist.github.com/wiverson/d2edf0d66ad195c96793d0d25290753b

As noted in the sample, OS native notifications are best if the app is in the background - use ControlsFX notifications if the app is in the foreground.

This works on macOS Big Sur, should also work on Windows. Not sure about Ubuntu.